# Can a Go function check how many of its return values are being consumed?

Tags: go

As per [Go's official tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), you can access an interface value's underlying concrete value using:

```
t := i.(T)
```

If `i` doesn't hold a `T`, the statement triggers a panic. If you do the following:

```
t, ok := i.(T)
```

...then there is no panic if `i` doesn't hold a `T`: we check the value of `ok` instead.

That means the behaviour of `i.(T)` depends on whether its second return value is consumed or not. Is it possible for a normal user-written function to check whether the calling line of code consumes the second (or third, or...) argument in this way? Or is this a special case?

**Note**: *Marked as duplicate because it is a compile-time error to not consume all of a function's arguments (except by using `_`). Given that all arguments must be consumed, the question becomes: can you have functions with a variable number of returned variables, which is addressed in the linked question.*

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Only one thing you can do to check the type of underlying value of interface is use `fmt.Printf("%T", i)`

Comment: You can find this feature in other parts of the language too: map access, some types of range statements, channel receives, to name a few. None of them are function calls so the question about a "special case" doesn't really apply.

Comment: I would argue that all of these are all, conceptually, function calls, just with special syntax.

Comment: @womblbombl: You might argue that, but you would be factually incorrect.

Comment: Struggling to find a neat software engineering language-agnostic definition of a function, but broadly I'd define a function (as opposed to a 'func' declaration in Go, which is one specific kind of the broader concept) as an operation which takes zero or more inputs and produces zero or more outputs. Then you have pure functions, which have no side effects, and are closer to the mathematical definition of a function. `i.(T)` is a pure function which maps two inputs (an interface value and type) to one output (a concrete value). The + operator is another 'non-func' pure function in this sense.